# How can I count and compare data over multiple columns in R?

Tags: r, count, frequency

I am working with a dataframe which contains text data which has been categorised and coded. Each numerical value from 1-12 represent a type of word.

I want to count the frequencies of occurrence each number (1 to 12) over 6 columns (pre1 to pre6) so I know how many types of words have been used. Could anyone please advise on how to do this?

My df is structured as such:

[image]

Comment: how about `table(unlist(pCat[,4:9]))`? This computes a table of all occurences in the columns 4 to 9. If you want a table of frequencies of just column `pre3` that is `table(pCat$pre3)`.

Comment: or `lapply(pCat[, 4:9], function(x){table(x)})` to get a list of 6 tables (one per column)

Comment: No idea where to find your dataset and no idea how the format of your ideal output should be. I'll post a solution which will hopefully help you...

Comment: @Bernhard - your solution is just what I'm looking for.

Comment: @ANG `table` is already a function of `x`. Shouldn't `lapply(pCat[,4:9], table)` suffice?

Comment: @llewmihs I made it an official answer and added a bit of explanation, why I think this is may be the better answer for you. If you want, you can mark an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like that work for you?

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(pre1 = c(sample(1:12, 10)),
                 pre2 = c(sample(1:12, 10)),
                 pre3 = c(sample(1:12, 10)),
                 pre4 = c(sample(1:12, 10)),
                 pre5 = c(sample(1:12, 10)),
                 pre6 = c(sample(1:12, 10)))
count <- count(df, pre1, pre2, pre3, pre4, pre5, pre6)
```

Comment: This solution will help counting combinations of numbers in each row, but doesn't consider each column separately.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is this:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  select(cyl, am, gear) %>%    # select the columns of interest
  gather(column, number) %>% # reshape
  count(column, number)      # get counts of numbers for each column

# # A tibble: 8 x 3
#   column number     n
#   <chr>   <dbl> <int>
# 1 am          0    19
# 2 am          1    13
# 3 cyl         4    11
# 4 cyl         6     7
# 5 cyl         8    14
# 6 gear        3    15
# 7 gear        4    12
# 8 gear        5     5
```

In your case `column` will get values as `pre1`, `pre2`, etc., `number' will get values 1 - 12 and`n` will be the count of a specific number at a specific column.

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear from the question, whether you want frequency tables for all of these columns together or for each column seperately. In possible further questions you should also make clear, whether those numbers are coded as numerics, as characters or as factors (the result of `str(pCat)` is a good way to do that). For this particular question, it fortunately does not matter.

The answers I have already given in the comments are

```
table(unlist(pCat[,4:9]))
```

and

```
table(pCat$pre3)
```

as an extension for the latter, I shall also point to the comment by ANG , which boils down to

```
lapply(pCat[,4:9], table)
```

These are straightforward solutions with base `R` without any further unneccessary packages. The answers by JonGrub and AntoniosK base on the tidyverse. There is no obvious need to import `dplyr` or `tidyverse` for this problem but I guess, the authors open those packages anyways, whenever they use `R`, so it does not really impose any cost on them. Other great packages to base good answers on are `data.table` and `sqldf`. Those are good packages and many people do a lot of things, that could be done in base `R` in one of these packages. The packages promise to be more clear or faster or reuse possible knowledge you might already have. Nothing is wrong with that. However, I take your question as an indication, that you are still learning `R` and I would advise, to learn `R` first, before you become distracted by learning special packages and DSLs.

People have been using base `R` for decades and they will continue to do so. Learning base `R` wil lnot distract you from `R` and the knowledge will continue to be worthwhile in decades. If the same can be said for the tidyverse or datatable, time will tell (although `sqldf` is probably also a solid investment in the future, maybe more so than `R`).